# Parsing data from a POST request in Python using requests module

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I have this function that I am using to get data from Influx DB.

```
def get_Oversightresponse():
        url = "http://172.16.26.252:8090/api/v2/query?org=mega&bucket=monitoring"
        payload="from(bucket: \"monitoring\")\r\n|> range(start: -60m, stop: now())\r\n|> filter(fn: (r) => r[\"_measurement\"] == \"snmp_trap\")\r\n|> pivot(rowKey:[\"_time\"], columnKey: [\"_field\"], valueColumn:\r\n\"_value\")\r\n|> map(fn: (r) => ({\r\ntime: r._time,\r\nlevel: r[\"engine.35.1.14.1.1\"],\r\nname: r[\"engine.35.1.14.1.2\"],\r\nsignaler: r[\"engine.35.1.14.1.3\"],\r\npayload: r[\"engine.35.1.14.1.6\"],\r\n}))\r\n|> filter(fn: (r) => r.level > 30 and r.name != \"signal-fetch-failed\")"

        headers = {'Authorization': 'Token secrettoken','Accept': 'application/csv','Content-Type': 'application/vnd.flux'}
        response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

        if response.status_code / 100 == 2:
                print(response.text)
        else:
                print("ERROR" + str(response.status_code))
```

The data I am getting from the above POST request is as follows:

```
,result,table,level,name,payload,signaler,time
,_result,0,50,HA STATE,"{""is_active"":""Active""}",aesi,2021-09-29T04:14:59.830020749Z
,_result,1,40,ROUTING_ENGINE_SVC_STATE,"{""state"":""stopped"",""timestamp"":""2021-09-29 00:14:09,518""}",ROUTING_ENGINE,2021-09-29T04:14:09.520427756Z
,_result,2,50,SVC_STATE,"{""Stopped_by_docker_container"":""Signal\u003d15""}",Agent_Manager_Service,2021-09-29T04:14:09.81728152Z
,_result,3,40,script_executor_SVC_STATE,"{""state"":""stopped"",""timestamp"":""2021-09-29 00:14:09,590""}",script_executor,2021-09-29T04:14:09.603449415Z
```

I need to parse it and sort the data timestamp wise. Can someone guide how this can be done?

Comment: *"Can someone guide how this can be done?"* - Yes. You use the `csv` module to split the data into columns you use `sorted()` to sort the rows.

Comment: Can you show me how?

Comment: As in *"Can you implement it for me so that I can copy and paste it?"* - no. I've given you pointers where to look and how to start, you write the code. There are thousands upon thousands of samples how to use the `csv` module, and how to sort things in Python. Do your research, write your code. You can ask a question here when you hit an issue with the code you wrote. But "please write it for me" is not a question.

Comment: Sure thanks I will give it a try.